# How can I store dynamic object array in mongodb using Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, mongodb, mongoose

I want to store data object array into mongodb as below format.

'

```
certifications' = {
                                  'certification1' = { 'name': ' SQL Server'},
  'certification2' = { 'name': 'Angular'},
....
}
```

Like wise I want to store data into monogodb field array.

Certiftication3, certifications4 it is dynamic it comes from client side.

How to acheive that functionality please help me...

Comment: so will the data coming from the client side look like this: [{"name": "google"}, {"name": "SQL Server"}]

Comment: Just updated code snippet can u pls look into it...

Answer (score 1):

Make a mongoose model like so:

```
const certificationSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        minlength: 3,
        maxlength: 255,
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('certification', certificationSchema);
```

in API route:

```
// certification.js

const Certification = require('../models/Certification');

// req.body = [{"name": "google"}, {"name": "SQL Server"}]

router.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
        // Model.insertMany() inserts an array of documents into a MongoDB collection should all of them be validated
        Certification.insertMany(req.body)
        .then((certification) => {
            if (certification) {
                   res.json(certification);
            } else {
                return next(new Error('Insertion failed'));
            }
        }).catch((err) => {
            next(err['message']);
        })
});
```